# Выход за пределы массива(не понимаю, почему)

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        String s1 = scanner.nextLine();
        List<Character> spicok = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Character> spicok2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Character> spicokAll = new ArrayList<>();
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        int Z = c.length;
        char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
        int Z1 = c1.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < Z-1; i++) {
            spicok.add(c[i]);

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < Z1-1; j++) {
            spicok2.add(c1[j]);

        }
        while (!spicok.equals(spicokAll)) {
            char a = spicok2.remove(0);
            spicokAll.add(a);
        }

        if (spicok.equals(spicokAll)) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else
             System.out.println("NO");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: в цикле while у вас ошибка, так как ссылки на два разных списка никогда не будут одинаковы

Comment: а вообще мне мало что понятно. опишите проблему пожробнее

Comment: Что ваша программа должна делать ?

Comment: А как мне можно исправить цикл?

Comment: Программа  должна выводить "YES" или "No" в зависимости от того, является ли вторая введенная строка циклическим сдвигом другой

Comment: На самом деле сравнение списков в Вашем случае идет по элементам как Вы и задумывали, а не по ссылкам как выше заметили. Метод equals переопределен.

Comment: Одна строка является циклическим сдвигом другой строки, если они будут равны после какого-то
количества циклических сдвигов одной из строк. Циклический сдвиг строки производится перемещением последнего символа в начало строки.
Например, ACTGACG является циклическим сдвигом строки TGACGAC, и наоборот. Нахождение и определение циклических сдвигов в геномах является очень важной составляющей изучения
геномов.
Это сама задача

Comment: Проблема в том что в spicok2 просто заканчиваются симоволы

Comment: да, в этом она и была. Спасибо большое

Comment: Но еще у Вас алгоритм неверный. Третий список Вам не нужен. Достаточно второго списка, но из которого удаляете символ в начале и вставляете его в конец. И границы циклов поправьте везде - на 1 символ не добегаете. Ответ писать не буду так как пример явно учебный. Лучше сами. Ну и если последовательности будут длинными - надо искать более быстрый алгоритм

Comment: @Анастасия , 1 - в цикле Z-1 , таким образом, когда вводишь qwerty , в список записывается q w e r t , вместо 6 , 5 элементов. 2 - Как уже написали, список кончается, 3 - реализация не совсем верна, просто происходит запись из одного списка в другой, и в итоге, в конце сравниваются те же значения, что у  spicok и spicok2, я накидал рабочий вариант, если хотите, скину

Comment: Было бы неплохо)

Comment: @GinTasan да не нужно никаких списков вообще, если существует такое `i` для которого `s1.startsWith(s2.substring(i)) && s1.endsWith(s2.substring(0, i))` истинно и при этом длины строк равны - ответ `YES`

Comment: @extrn , 1 - напишите ответ со своей реализацией 2 - Сомнения на счет количества возвращаемых String объектов для сравнения 3 - Знаю, что вариант можно улучшить, но автор запросил решение проблемы его кода, я хочу привести ближайшую его реализацию выполнения, что бы автору было понятно, что , как и какие ошибки

Comment: @GinTasan выложил, хотя сомневаюсь, что автор оценит. Можно конечно переделать без функциональщины, но думаю не стоит чинить не сломанное.

Comment: @extrn , Автор, как я понял, новичек, поэтому, возможно такое будет мало понятно, а ,так , ради интереса бы посмотрел на оптимизированный вариант, ибо на моей машинке ваш вариант в среднем, в 5 раз мелденнее

Comment: @GinTasan https://ideone.com/9SpzOy разница в производительности есть, но не в 5 раз, на несколько процентов. Оба варианта одинаково плохи по производительности, ваш из за `remove(0)`, мой из за `substring`, и то и другое приводит к полному копированию строк на каждом шагу. Приложил к тестам оптимизированный вариант, он гораздо быстрее, но на строках, которые __почти__ совпадают все равно будет работать медленно уже на этапе `equals`. На такой случай есть специальные эффективные строковые алгоритмы, но это уже отдельный разговор.

Comment: @extrn , Благодарю за реализацию, и за вариант, спасибо )

Comment: @GinTasan И вам спасибо. :) Ответ удалил, все-таки он был предназначен не ОПу.

Answer (score 1):

Рабочая версия циклического сдвига, ваши неточности в коде:

- В цикле Z-1 , таким образом, когда вводишь qwerty , в список записывается q w e r t , вместо 6 , 5 элементов.
- Как уже написали(@dSH), список кончается.
- Реализация не совсем верна, просто происходит запись из одного списка в другой, и в итоге, в конце сравниваются те же значения, что у spicok и spicok2.
- Советую почитать про структуры данных, дабы освежить память

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        String s1 = scanner.nextLine();

        List<Character> spicok = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Character> spicok2 = new ArrayList<>();

        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        int Z = c.length;

        char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
        int Z1 = c1.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < Z; i++) {
            spicok.add(c[i]);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < Z1; j++) {
            spicok2.add(c1[j]);
        }


        for(int i=0 ; i< spicok2.size();i++) {
            if(spicok.equals(spicok2)) break;

            spicok2.add(spicok2.remove(0));

            }

        if (spicok.equals(spicok2)) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else
             System.out.println("NO");
        }
```